# Getting User Information from Django Python Social Auth in the view

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

First time working with python-social-auth and Django but having trouble figuring out exactly how much information about the user's social account is available to me.

---

When I access the `extra_data` of the UserSocialAuth object I can get the uid, and the access_token. To get additional details am I to feed those through the social company's (ex facebook) API?

---

I can see that for some social auths like facebook Django's `user` object is magically populated with the first and last names from the social profile, but for others like LinkedIn that doesn't work. How do i find out which information is available for each social auth without manually probing each one?

---

I'm just trying to get as much "Profile" data from the user and am worried going through the API is the "long way" of achieving this. I have actually read through the documentation but it may be too advanced for me; im not sure how to use the data that is acquired by the pipeline from the view. I'm not even sure if that sentence makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-social-auth` will just fetch the necessarily bits to fill:

- email
- username
- first name
- last name

Some APIs will provide more details during the authentication flow, those can be saved in `extra_data` based on the [SOCIAL_AUTH_EXTRA_DATA](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/oauth.html?highlight=EXTRA_DATA) setting.

Some backends will issue a call to an API in the provider to fetch the extra data. An easy way to debug the data available, is to add a custom pipeline in between the default steps and print everything in the args.

As per the `uid` and `access_token`, yes, you are right, when calling any API served by the provider will require these values, sometimes both, sometimes `access_token` is enough.